# How to use DbGeography.Filter in Linq with Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, spatial

With Entity Framework 5 it is possible to use the SQL Server Spatial procedures in Linq queries.

For example, using a DbGeography object, you can use the "Buffer()" method which will translate to STBuffer in SQL Server. Same way, Intersects() will translate to STIntersects.

This is an example query that works:

```
  var point = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", latitude, longitude), 4326);
  var query = from person in persons
              let region = point.Buffer(radius)
              where person.Location.Intersects(region)
              select person;
```

I would like to use the **Filter** possibility (since this can speed up your queries if accuracy is not your main concern as pointed out here: http://www.pauldmendoza.com/post/SQL-Server-Filter-vs-STInterects.aspx)
However, I can't seem to find how to do this in EF5. Is this possible? And if yes: how?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asked the question a bit too soon. I found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673622(v=vs.110).aspx

And this can be used like this:

```
  var point = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", latitude, longitude), 4326);
  var query = from person in persons
              let region = point.Buffer(radius)
              where SqlSpatialFunctions.Filter(person.Location, region) == true
              select person;
```

And this translates to the query I wanted.

Comment: Just a quick note - 'POINT' expects first longitude not latitude

Comment: That's true, but I added the {1} before the {0} so the example is correct

Comment: haven't noticed that one

Comment: what would be the optimal radius value?